# How to Exclude only the special character like #, $, % etc and include alphabet and Numbers in a search Query?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a Search box on my site and when ever the user types in the special character like @,#,$ etc I am replacing all the non standard character with empty space 
term.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g," "); 
in javaScript
But this code Will replace all the number from 0-9 to empty. How Do i make the search box to be include Numbers(apart from Alphabets) and only exclude Special characters.

Comment: Is à considered a "special" character? What about ß?

Comment: Like this? term.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g," ")

Comment: @quentin Special characters that a regular Keyboard has from American English stand point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
term.replace(/\W|_/g," ");
```

[JS Fiddle proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7kMYD/).

References:

- [RegExp, at the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Comment: @ David Thomas but i don't want to even _ to sent over. I want to exclude the _ too. Will this regex work like that. I have some exception on my backend if i send the _ from UI

Comment: I think i looked at the fiddle it is handling it too. Sorry for confusion

Comment: This reg-ex will take all non alpha-numeric characters, including the `_`, and replace them with a space. It's a more concise version of `replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi,' ')` is all. Because the `\W` normally allows the `_` I've had to explicitly add it in to be removed.

Comment: @ David Thomas The solution you have provided will work across all the Browsers. What i mean is this cross browser compatible?

Comment: Works in Firefox 10, and Chromium 16 on Ubuntu 11.04; other than that I'm unable to say. I think it should work in IE, but you'd need someone with Internet Explorer to test.

Comment: I test across safari 4.x, IE8/IE9/IE7 and Mozilla 3.x and this Code works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this:

```
term.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g," ");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
term.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g," ");
```

The regex part of that line of code is

```
/[^A-Za-z]/g
```

That says "not a letter, of any case". To add in numbers, so it says "Not a letter of any case, or a number", you want

```
/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g
```

It then replaces those characters (ie. anything that's not alphanumeric) with a blank string (ie. removes them).

Comment: Why not just use the case-insensitive flag: `replace(/[^a-z]/gi," ");`?

Comment: 6 and 2x3 :) He had a-zA-Z in there originally, I kept it there.

Comment: @David Thomas. Thanks for bringing the case- sensitive feature in to Picture I was not' sure what that 'g', 'i' was  and since you mentioned it i started looking in to the RegEx Docucment. So Regex start making sense